# What does the phrase "move-blocking seven of hearts beneath the six" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase"move-blocking seven of hearts beneath the six" in the following sentence:

> You can drop that **move-blocking seven of hearts beneath the six**, but
>   it doesn't mean that would make the game easier because it would add
>   new layers of complexity.

Maybe I am missing a very technical aspect or rule of cards.

Comment: It's impossible to know exactly what it means without knowing what card game is being talked about. All we can say is that the seven of hearts is blocking a move in some way.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  The game's name is Solitaire.

Comment: "Solitaire" means any one-player card game. There are many.

Comment: What is the specific part of that phrase (aside from the meaning of each word) that is confusing?

Comment: @JasonBassford I am not sure about the process. How does the word "beneath" make sense here?

Comment: In Solitaire, you play by placing one card *beneath* another one. (It could be argued that it goes *on top of* another one, but that's only along one axis, so it's a matter of perspective.)

Comment: I think the implication is "*cheat* by moving the 7 to under the six" when the usual rules would require you to move the 6 on to the top of the 7. I half suspect the use here is metaphorical "You might be able to achieve short term goals by cheating, but it makes your life more complex in the long run".  So *What is the exact source of the quoted text* Please **cite sources**

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the game, I can't say exactly what it means, but I can explain the grammar.

The structure is "you can drop [that move-blocking seven of hearts] [beneath the six]": it's like "you can drop that seven beneath the six", but with extra modifiers on "seven".

"Move-blocking" modifies "seven": "a move-blocking seven" is *a seven that blocks a move*. This is the same structure as "a plant-eating animal": an animal that eats plants.

"Beneath the six" isn't part of the noun phrase; it's another argument to *drop*: it tells where to put the seven.

So apparently this seven is getting in the way of some other move, and it's possible to get rid of it by dropping it beneath the six.

Comment: The game's name is Solitaire.

Answer (score 0):

The author *might* have meant to use "move-blocking" as a word.  But:

### The hyphen is probably a dash.

You wrote:

> You can drop that move-blocking seven of hearts beneath the six, but
>   it doesn't mean that would make the game easier because it would add
>   new layers of complexity.

Another possibility here is the following:

> You can drop that move -- blocking seven of hearts beneath the six, but
>   *it doesn't mean* that would make the game easier because it would add
>   new layers of complexity.

*It doesn't mean* is not very good -- "it" is ambiguous, and it should probably say "that" or be **re-written**.

The above version means:

> You can **try that play**.   You can **block** the 7 of hearts beneath the 6, but
>   *it doesn't mean that* would make the game easier because it would add
>   new layers of complexity.

Let's keep simplifying:

> You can **do that**.   You can put the 7 of hearts underneath the 6.
>
> But **doing that** does not mean the game will get easier.
>
> **Doing that** would add new layers of complexity.
>
> *or:*
>   **That** would add new layers of complexity.